# Rx Merge + CombineLatest?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

The `CombineLatest` starts when both observables have started.

```
A     1----------2---------------
B     -----a----------b---c------
C     -----1a----2a---2b--2c-----   C = A.CombineLatest(B)
```

The `Merge` operator starts when either A or B have started. However, it can't combine A and B latest values.

```
A     1----------2---------------
B     -----a----------b---c------
C     1----a-----2----b---c------   C = A.Merge(B)
```

I need an operator behaving like `Merge` except that it would allow me to combine A and B latest values when both observable have started :

```
A    1----------2---------------
B    -----a----------b---c------
C    1----1a----2a---2b--2c-----   C = A.MergeOrCombineLatest(B)
```

Its signature might look like this :

```
Observable<C> MergeOrCombineLatest<A, B, C>(
     this IObservable<A> a,
     IObservable<B> b,
     Func<A, C> aResultSelector, // When A starts before B
     Func<B, C> bResultSelector, // When B starts before A
     Func<A, B, C> bothResultSelector) // When both A and B have started
```

How could this operator be implemented ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me:

```
public static IObservable<C> MergeOrCombineLatest<A, B, C>(
    this IObservable<A> a,
    IObservable<B> b,
    Func<A, C> aResultSelector, // When A starts before B
    Func<B, C> bResultSelector, // When B starts before A
    Func<A, B, C> bothResultSelector) // When both A and B have started
{
    return
        a.Publish(aa =>
            b.Publish(bb =>
                aa.CombineLatest(bb, bothResultSelector).Publish(xs =>
                    aa
                        .Select(aResultSelector)
                        .Merge(bb.Select(bResultSelector))
                        .TakeUntil(xs)
                        .SkipLast(1)
                        .Merge(xs))));
}
```

Then this:

```
var a = new Subject<int>();
var b = new Subject<string>();

var C = a.MergeOrCombineLatest(b, x => $"{x}!!", y => $"{y}!!", (x, y) => $"{x}{y}");

C.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));

b.OnNext("x");
b.OnNext("y");
b.OnNext("z");
a.OnNext(1);
a.OnNext(5);
a.OnNext(6);
b.OnNext("a");
a.OnNext(2);
b.OnNext("b");
b.OnNext("c");
```

...gives this:

```
x!!
y!!
z!!
1z
5z
6z
6a
2a
2b
2c
```

Answer (score 1):

First you choose special values for A, B that your Observables will never emit, let it be null:

```
A specialA = null;
B specialB = null;
```

then

```
Observable<C> MergeOrCombineLatest<A, B, C>(
  this IObservable<A> a,
  IObservable<B> b,
  Func<A, C> aResultSelector, // When A starts before B
  Func<B, C> bResultSelector, // When B starts before A
  Func<A, B, C> bothResultSelector) // When both A and B have started
{
  return a.StartWith(specialA).CombineLatest(b.StartWith(specialB), 
    (aval, bval) => {
      if (aval == specialA) return bval == specialB ? default(C) : bResultSelector(bval);
      if (bval == specialB) return aResultSelector(bval);
      return bothResultSelector(aval, bval);
    }
  ).skip(1);  // skip the first emission where both are special values
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that is a very nice solution. Instead of choosing a "special value", I think I will box each element inside a `Tuple<bool, T>` where the boolean value indicates wether it is the starting element or not. Thank very much for your help !

Comment: The use of the `Maybe<T>` monad would be awesome for the special values - this would allow value types to be used or for `null` to be allowable values.